# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch is not recognized in chrome and on ios

Tags: ios, css, cordova, meteor, webkit

To get the inertial scroll I have read I need to add -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; to my css on the div that scrolls. When I add this and inspect it in chrome that code is stricken, similar to when you try to use css that is not valid. Also when I load this on my iPhone (I am using cordova in a meteor app), I still do not get the smooth scrolling. I have added

```
z-index:0
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
```

As well as making the containers positioned absolute. None of this seems to work. is webkit-overflow-scrolling deprecated? Any help would be appreciated

p.s My css is in a Scss file (if that matters)

Comment: -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch working for Android + IOS. Do you add css in parent of scrolling content?

Comment: @HanhLe yes I do, i tried both the parent and the actual div itself

Comment: Please show your  html structure. It working in my app.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some more css fixed it for me, i get the smooth scroll in ios safari like this:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

If its a webb app it might work for you too!